# Wordpress displaying two different headers, one at top and one below footer

Tags: theme-development

I am building a custom WP theme for the first time. Just started trying to put specific header template files with my different page templates. For some reason, when I use "get_header(X)" to call a specific header template, the page in the browser displays the correct header at the top, but then replicates the main header (from header.php) at the end of the page, below the footer.

[image: Homepage displaying correctly]

[image: EYFS" type page displaying correct, different header at top, with the main header incorrectly replicated below the footer]

I can't see where in the code this is being called from, but when I look at the source in browser, it is clear to see the full contents of header.php inserted below the footer. Have included the code from my "page-eyfs.php" template, which calls the 'eyfs' header template at the start.

Site is only local currently

```
    <?php
/**
* The header for our theme
*
* This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
*
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
*
* @package thatnurserylife
*/

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>

<!Adding Google Fonts into Header so that they will apply on all pages. Will call the fonts directly from style.css!>

<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mali|Questrial&display=swap');

    .headertitle{
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Mali', cursive;
    font-size: 3vw;

    }

    .headertitlebold{
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .headerboxes{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .headerboxesside{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;

    }

    .headerboxesmid{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
    min-width: 500px;

    }

    .headerlogo{
    height: 15em;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }

.clearfix::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
</style>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>


<div id="page" class="site">
<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'thatnurserylife' ); ?></a>

    <header>   
     <div class="headerboxes">
        <div class="headerboxesside" style="background-color:#fff">
            <p>     </p>
        </div>

        <div class="headerboxesmid" style="background-color:#fff">

            <img class="headerlogo" src="/wp-content/uploads/logo.png" alt="Should be a logo here!" /> 
            <div class="headertitle">
            <h> all you need to love <br><strong>thatnurserylife</strong></h>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="headerboxesside" style="background-color:#fff">
            <p>  </p>
        </div>

     </div>

        <!-- .site-branding -->



            </div>


    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'thatnurserylife' ); ?></button>
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
        ) );
        ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</header>   <!-- #masthead -->

<div id="content" class="site-content">
```

^This is the code for the main/homepage header, which appears correctly^

```
<?php
/**
* The header for our theme
*
* This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
*
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
*
* @package thatnurserylife
*/

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>

<!Adding Google Fonts into Header so that they will apply on all pages. Will call the fonts directly from style.css!>

<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mali|Questrial&display=swap');

    .headertitle{
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Mali', cursive;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 4em;

    }

    .headertitlebold{
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .headerboxes{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .headerboxesside{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;

    }

    .headerboxesmid{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;

    }

    .headerlogo{
    height: 15em;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }

.clearfix::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
 display: table;
}
</style>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>


<div id="page" class="site">
<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'thatnurserylife' ); ?></a>

    <header>   
     <div class="headerboxes">
        <div class="headerboxesside" style="background-color:#fff">
            <p>     </p>
        </div>

        <div class="headerboxesmid" style="background-color:#fff">

            <img class="headerlogo" src="/wp-content/uploads/EYFS_logo.png" alt="Should be EYFS logo here!" /> 
            <div class="headertitle">
            <h> EYFS Activity Plans</h>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="headerboxesside" style="background-color:#fff">
            <p>  </p>
        </div>

     </div>

        <!-- .site-branding -->



            </div>


    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'thatnurserylife' ); ?></button>
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
        ) );
        ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</header>   <!-- #masthead -->

<div id="content" class="site-content">
```

^This is the code for the alternative header which is displaying correctly at the top, with the main header incorrectly displayed beneath the footer^

```
    <?php /* Template Name: EYFS type */ ?>
<?php
/**
* 
* The template for displaying all pages
*
* This is the template that displays all pages by default.
* Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
* and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
* different template.
*
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
* @package thatnurserylife
*/

get_header('eyfs');


?>

<div>
    <h2>This is an EYFS type page</h2>
</div>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;

    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

^This is the code from the EYFS page template^

Comment: Hello! Can you edit your question to include code for those headers and the template involved? It's not possible to debug the problem from just screenshots

Comment: Thanks for responding - have added the bits of code. In copying it I noticed that my alternative header template doesn't have a "Template Name" bit at the top of the code in the way that the page template does - could this be the problem?

Comment: headers don't need template name comments at the top, but your page template file does or it won't show up as an option in the editor

Comment: And you're absolutely sure that `template-parts/content-page.php` or `template-parts/content.php` don't contain a call to `get_header`?

Comment: Yep, they definately don't have that call, nor any reference to headers so far as I can see

Comment: And if you search your entire codebase in your editor for `get_header` those are the only 2 references? Be sure to search with the editor, not manually

Comment: What's in sidebar.php and footer.php?

Comment: So I've searched the code base using the editor. The only get_header() appearences are:

page.php (this one calls the main header)
page-eyfs.php (this one calls the 'eyfs' header)

Sidebar & Footer just have what was automatically created in them by the base theme - I haven't made any adjustments. Sidebar has nothing at all, and Footer is just some code for the "Proudly made by Wordpress" and the theme details